# Can this Youtube code be modified to force autoplay?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a [Youtube Carousel](https://codepen.io/derwinsadiwa/pen/obbjdx) with code I want to use but I want the videos to autoplay the way they do on Youtube but in this example you have to click on them. I am sure there is someone here who can probably do that. A lot of people want something like this. I want to share this with a lot of people because they don't know how to code it themselves.

Here is the code

```js
/*JS FOR SCROLLING THE ROW OF THUMBNAILS*/ 
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.vid-item').each(function(index){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
      var current_index = index+1;
      $('.vid-item .thumb').removeClass('active');
      $('.vid-item:nth-child('+current_index+') .thumb').addClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
     margin: 30px;
     padding: 0;
     background: #ddd;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .title {
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 854px;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .caption {
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 854px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 20px 0;
    }

    .vid-main-wrapper {
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 1100px;
     min-width: 440px;
     background: #fff;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }


    /*  VIDEO PLAYER CONTAINER
   ############################### */
    .vid-container {
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 52%;
      padding-top: 30px; 
      height: 0; 
        width:70%;
        float:left;
  }
   
  .vid-container iframe,
  .vid-container object,
  .vid-container embed {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 360px;
  }


  /*  VIDEOS PLAYLIST 
   ############################### */
  .vid-list-container {
   width: 30%;
      height:360px;
   overflow: hidden;
      float:right;
  }

    .vid-list-container:hover, .vid-list-container:focus {
       overflow-y: auto;
     }

  ol#vid-list {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      background: #222;
  }

    ol#vid-list li {
    list-style: none;
    }

    ol#vid-list li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #222;
      height:55px;
      display:block;
      padding:10px;
    }

    ol#vid-list li a:hover {
      background-color:#666666
    }

  .vid-thumb {
      float:left;
   margin-right: 8px;
  }

    .active-vid { 
      background:#3A3A3A;
    }

  #vid-list .desc {
   color: #CACACA;
   font-size: 13px;
   margin-top:5px;
  }


  @media (max-width: 624px) {
   body {
    margin: 15px;
   }
   .caption {
    margin-top: 40px;
   }
   .vid-list-container {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
   }

  }
```

```html
<div class="vid-main-wrapper clearfix">

        <!-- THE YOUTUBE PLAYER -->
      <div class="vid-container">
          <iframe id="vid_frame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cOSEOYi9JS4?rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
      </div>

      <!-- THE PLAYLIST -->
      <div class="vid-list-container">
            <ol id="vid-list">
              <li>
                <a href="javascript:void();" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://youtube.com/embed/cOSEOYi9JS4?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1'">
                  <span class="vid-thumb"><img width=72 src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/cOSEOYi9JS4/default.jpg" /></span>
                  <div class="desc">WeatherBeater™ Product Video</div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript:void();" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://youtube.com/embed/9P7mEf4bilg?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1'">
                  <span class="vid-thumb"><img width=72 src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/9P7mEf4bilg/default.jpg" /></span>
                  <div class="desc">X-act Contour® Product Video</div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript:void();" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://youtube.com/embed/KHxNpXovl58?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1'">
                  <span class="vid-thumb"><img width=72 src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/KHxNpXovl58/default.jpg" /></span>
                  <div class="desc">GearBox® Product Video</div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript:void();" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://youtube.com/embed/D_a2UBGsePQ?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1'">
                  <span class="vid-thumb"><img width=72 src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/D_a2UBGsePQ/default.jpg" /></span>
                  <div class="desc">Mud Guards Product Video</div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript:void();" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://youtube.com/embed/vYoh2IgoBXg?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1'">
                  <span class="vid-thumb"><img width=72 src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/vYoh2IgoBXg/default.jpg" /></span>
                  <div class="desc">Wheel Well Guards Product Video</div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript:void();" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://youtube.com/embed/RTHI_uGyfTM?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1'">
                  <span class="vid-thumb"><img width=72 src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/RTHI_uGyfTM/default.jpg" /></span>
                  <div class="desc">Cargo Liner Product Video</div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript:void();" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://youtube.com/embed/EvTjAjLNphE?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1'">
                  <span class="vid-thumb"><img width=72 src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/EvTjAjLNphE/default.jpg" /></span>
                  <div class="desc">Husky Liners Products</div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript:void();" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame').src='https://youtube.com/embed/-Qpc79oaJQg?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1'">
                  <span class="vid-thumb"><img width=72 src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/-Qpc79oaJQg/default.jpg" /></span>
                  <div class="desc">Custom Molded Mud Guards</div>
                </a>
              </li>
              
            </ul>
       </div>

   
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains the `lazy load` method to avoid a horrendous page load time. If you do not load a video after the `DOM` has been loaded, your page will load extremely slow because it waits for the video to load. Also, if mobile users (whom are not on a wi-fi connection) visit your site, they will use quite some resources of their data bundle/plans.

That being said, the answer would be to replace your `img` elements with an `iframe` element. After that you can add the `?autoplay=1` parameter to the end of the YouTube URL. Your YouTube URLs already contain that parameter, so ideally you would replace your `a` (`anchor`) tags with the following code:

```
<a href="javascript:void();">
  <iframe id="vid_frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/vYoh2IgoBXg?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
  <div class="desc">Wheel Well Guards Product Video</div>
</a>
```

Where the `src property` of the `iframe` element have to be replaced with the YouTube video of your choice. You can also modify the `height` and `width` properties.

Comment: Stefan R

Well your code makes the videos autoplay which is what I asked for but now they all play at the same time. Is there a way to have them only autoplay one at a time and only if there is not one already playing?  You did great so far though and I appreciate you devoting your time on this.

Comment: @Superfast You're welcome. I doubt that is possible without ``appending`` the ``iframes`` to the ``DOM`` every few seconds by using the ``setTimeout`` function in ``JavaScript``. However, that would mean the YouTube videos won't be visible before they are being ``appended`` to the ``DOM``. For that you could use a part of the logic of the placeholder images of the YouTube video in your original code. In the end this would mean the ``IMG`` element will be replaced by an ``iframe`` element via ``JavaScript``

Comment: So then it is possible to have it function the same way it does on Youtube. So what I glean from what you're saying here is two iframes would be required with additional javascript for each video is that correct? If that is correct can you show an example of how that could work?  I know I'm asking a lot but I can't code something like that, coders are a different breed of human and I wasn't born into that breed. LOL

Comment: I'm kinda lost what at you're trying to achieve. Take a look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98cxwLt3). The only thing I changed at this moment is the ``autoplay=1&mute=1`` parameter in the first video (line 5). If you click on a video it will autoplay. Or do you want all thumbnails to autoplay subsequently?

Comment: @Stefen R:  Yes I want them to all autoplay subsequently like it does on the example located here, 

http://giorgio003.github.io/Youtube-TV/demos/responsive.html

Here is the page with other demos of Youtube Carousel style players 

https://github.com/Giorgio003/Youtube-TV#demos

I cannot figure out how to port the code over to my web page.  His instructions seem to be missing many steps. Maybe you will have better luck figuring out how make things work on a personal page.

Comment: @Stefen,

Here is a better example of what I would love to have on my personal page. The only thing is that it does not autoplay any videos.

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/media-player/examples/functionality/playlist/defaultcs.aspx#

I can't figure out how to port something like this over to my personal page. That would really be something to have a player that works like this one.